# CSF Firewall unblock countries

Tags: firewall, csf

I've a VPS Server running CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 with CSF Firewall activated. Sometimes I see in "Firewall Deny IPs" that blocks suddenly connections from my country (Spain) to some of my clients.

Not with everybody and not everyday, but 2-3 times per week I've to unblock manually some of my clients' IPs because CSF is blocking them.

How can I configure it for not blocking connections from Spain and working the same way until now with the rest of the world? I don't want to connect ONLY from Spain, I want not to block any IP from Spain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at CC_ALLOW

CC_ALLOW = ES

WARNING: CC_ALLOW allows access through all ports in the firewall. For this
reason CC_ALLOW probably has very limited use and CC_ALLOW_FILTER is
preferred

Personally I would look at why they are being blocked rather than blanket allowing them.